# IFormFiles always receive a null even if the form has the enctype="multipart/form-data" tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Could anyone tell me what does asp.net core `mvc framework` does when we specify a [FromBody] tag in a method?

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult register ([FromBody]CustomerViewModel custView)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     repo.create_customer(custView);
     return Ok(custView);
    }
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

and here is the view model that we want to receive.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name!")]
     public string name { get; set; }

     //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please upload your resume!")]
     //public IFormFile cv { get; set; }

}
```

I notice that when I am not using [FromBody] tag, I can still receive the object(has file as attribute) correctly, and when I add the [FromBody], it cannot receive file stream through http, just why do we even want to use [FromBody] tag to receive http post?

---

forgot to mention, it didn't work even with the multipart-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the content type on the form to "multipart/form-data". This is the one we should use when uploading files. The spec is https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, I did it by following the doc, so I have the multipart-tag with the html though, but it still didn't work.